# AWS Glue table partitions for data stored in multiple buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a Glue table with 10s of thousands of partitions with the following partition keys:

```
"PartitionKeys": [
    {
        "Name": "thing",
        "Type": "string"
    },
    {
        "Name": "year",
        "Type": "string"
    },
    {
        "Name": "date",
        "Type": "string"
    }
]
```

Each partition location in S3 has 168 files of various sizes (7 parquet files per hour in the day).

On larger Athena queries I'm getting the error

```
Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: 503 Slow Down
```

When I look at detail metrics on S3 Get Requests, I can see large spikes in GET and HEAD requests on the bucket.

I'm currently using a single S3 bucket to store the data

Can I can store my parquet files in multiple buckets, and update the Glue table partitions to use locations in multiple buckets so that Athena queries are spread out among more buckets.

Something like (in boto3):

```py
import boto3

glue = boto3.client('glue')

glue.batch_create_partition(
    DatabaseName='myDatabase',
    TableName='myTable',
    PartitionInputList=[
        {
            "Values": [
                "thing-1",
                "2020",
                "2020-01-24"
            ],
            "StorageDescriptor": {
                # Note S3 bucket
                "Location": "s3://my-data-bucket-1/thing=thing-1/year=2020/date=2020-01-24",
                # Ignoring other requred items in StorageDescriptor
            }
        },
        {
            "Values": [
                "thing-2",  # Different thing
                "2020",
                "2020-01-24"
            ],
            "StorageDescriptor": {
                # Different S3 bucket
                "Location": "s3://my-other-data-bucket-2/thing=thing-2/year=2020/date=2020-01-24",
                # Ignoring other requred items in StorageDescriptor
            }
        }
        # Ignoring other required items in PartitionInputList
    ]
)
```

Comment: The root of the problem is that the number of files per partition. Have you tried creating a single file per partition and retry running the query? This will atleast reduce the requests 168 files X 2 and becomes 1 file X 2 requests

Comment: I've considered this, but I'm trying to keep the S3 objects at the [optimal file size](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/) (Tip #4), and combining would make these objects too big in most cases.